# Nohup not recording the output to the screen

Tags: linux, python, nohup

I try to use nohup to record the output of my python script. However, I can see the output to the screen when I am not using nohup.

> Start at XX:XX:XX
>
> Finished at XX:XX:XX

But then I use nohup but the nohup.out file is empty. Anyone got a hint of what is going on?

This is the command I used :

```
nohup python myPython.py &
```

I tried nohup before and it work perfectly good. I also tried to run some short test python script to record the output and it is good, too.

The test script is short and simple:

```
string1 = ["John","1","2","0","f","a","s"]
line = [""]*6
line[3:6] = string1 [0:3]
print line
```

Comment: did you add a shebang? `#!/usr/bin/env python`

Comment: also try: `nohup ./myPython.py &` rather than `nohup myPython.py &`

Comment: Yes I added the shebang already. Actually, I tried with the test script i just use `nohup python myPython.py &` , and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer, the stdout is not flushed automatically.

You can change it to unbuffered mode, e.g

```
sys.stdout = os.fdopen(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'w', 0)
```

See the following link for more details

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-python-print

Comment: Actually, I just got to know that the output is stored in the nohup.out when the script is finished.  However, I can see there are output in nohup.out file even it is in the middle of execution.